# Why do I get "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time" when iterating a nested vector?

Tags: rust

I want to iterate two nested vectors ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=921bbfd02033a2d13af5ea114bd79d5d)):

```rust
struct Name {
    index: usize,
    data: Vec<String>,
}

impl Name {
    fn new(test: bool) -> Option<Name> {
        if test {
            Some(Name {
                index: 0,
                data: vec![String::from("ATGCTA"), String::from("ACGTGA")],
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index < self.data.len() {
            Some(self.data[self.index - 1].as_bytes())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct Data {
    index: usize,
    data: Vec<Option<Name>>,
}

impl Data {
    fn new() -> Data {
        Data {
            index: 0,
            data: vec![Name::new(true)],
        }
    }

    fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        let max_index = self.data.len() - 1;
        let record = self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record();
        match record {
            None => {
                if self.index < max_index {
                    self.index += 1;
                    return self.iter_record();
                }
            }
            _ => {}
        }
        record
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data::new();
    while let Some(ret) = data.iter_record() {
        println!("{:?}", ret);
    }
}
```

Here is the build error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:47:28
   |
40 |     fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
   |                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
41 |         let max_index = self.data.len() - 1;
42 |         let record = self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record();
   |                      --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
47 |                     return self.iter_record();
   |                            ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
52 |         record
   |         ------ returning this value requires that `self.data` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Why does this error occur? How do I solve it?

Comment: does it need to be called recursively? You could write a while loop instead.

Comment: I have tried a loop, but get a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [some parts](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions) of the NLL were not implemented in the compiler, because they are too CPU intensive. As a result the compiler cannot recognize that the borrow does not extend outside of the `match`. In the general case the  **workaround** is to wrap it in an `if` statement that **unconditionally** returns. The downside is that the code would be slower at runtime, because it would need to do the same check twice. This mechanism is much better explained in the linked document.

```rust
 fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        let max_index = self.data.len() - 1;

        // This will not really work in your case, because you are modifying the struct's state, thus each method invocation will produce a different result
        let check = self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record();
        if check.is_some() {
            match self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record() {
                Some(r) => return Some(r),
                None => unreachable!(),
            }
        }

        if self.index < max_index {
            self.index += 1;
            return self.iter_record();
        }

        None
    }
```

Unfortunately in your case this will not work, because your `Name::iter_record()` modifies the internal state of the structure, thus it's not possible to call it twice. In order to resolve that issue I'll introduce a new method `peek_record()` which will just return `true` or `false` depending on whether `iter_record()` would have returned `Some` or `None` if called instead:

```rust
 fn peek_record(&self) -> bool {
        self.index + 1 < self.data.len()
    }
```

This would result in the following [working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f2866f0a1bf91811aa0f0606b5204e6):

```rust
struct Name {
    index: usize,
    data: Vec<String>,
}

impl Name {
    fn new(test: bool) -> Option<Name> {
        if test {
            Some(Name {
                index: 0,
                data: vec![String::from("ATGCTA"), String::from("ACGTGA")],
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index < self.data.len() {
            Some(self.data[self.index - 1].as_bytes())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn peek_record(&self) -> bool {
        self.index + 1 < self.data.len()
    }
}

struct Data {
    index: usize,
    data: Vec<Option<Name>>,
}

impl Data {
    fn new() -> Data {
        Data {
            index: 0,
            data: vec![Name::new(true)],
        }
    }

    fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        let max_index = self.data.len() - 1;

        if self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().peek_record() {
            match self.data[self.index].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record() {
                Some(r) => return Some(r),
                None => unreachable!(),
            }
        }

        if self.index < max_index {
            self.index += 1;
            return self.iter_record();
        }

        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data::new();
    while let Some(ret) = data.iter_record() {
        println!("{:?}", ret);
    }
}
```

PS: You can further simplify your code by getting rid of the recursion:

```
    fn iter_record(&mut self) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        for idx in self.index..self.data.len() {
            if self.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap().peek_record() {
                match self.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap().iter_record() {
                    Some(r) => return Some(r),
                    None => unreachable!(),
                }
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }

        None
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and code, there is an error in the last code block, `self.index += 1;` should be placed in the else block.

Comment: @Moold you are right. The `self.index += 1;` can actually be moved after the `if`, because it always returns when it evaluates to true

Comment: "NLL" stands for [non-lexical lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html).